# PHP Self-referencing form

Tags: php, html, forms, self-reference

I'm taking a PHP course, using the Head First PHP and MYSQL textbook. The book was written back in 2008 so I am constantly wondering if what I'm learning is up to date.

The text book shows a self-referencing html form in php comments like this:

```
<?php
    require_once('appvars.php');
    require_once('connectvars.php');

    if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['date']) && isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['score']) && isset($_GET['screenshot'])) {

            // Grab the score data from the Get
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $date = $_GET['date'];
            $name = $_GET['name'];
            $score = $_GET['score'];
            $screenshot = $_GET['screenshot'];                
        }
    else if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['score'])) {

        // Grab the score data from the POST
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $score = $_POST['score'];
        }
        else {
            echo '<p class="error">Sorry, no high score was specified for removal.</p>';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
            if ($_POST['confirm'] == 'Yes') {
                // Delete the screen shot image file from the server
                @unlink(GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot);

                 //Connect to the database
                $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

                // Delete the score data from the database
                $query = "DELETE FROM guitarwars WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";
                $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
                    or die('Unable to complete query');
                mysqli_close($dbc);  

                // Confirm success with the user
                echo '<p>The high score of ' . $score . ' for ' . $name . ' was succesfully removed.';
            }
            else {
                echo '<p class="error">The high score was not removed.</p>';
            }
        }

        else if (isset($id) && isset($name) && isset($date) && 
                isset($score) && isset($screenshot)) {
                    echo '<p>Are you sure you want to delete the following high score?</p>';
                    echo '<p><strong>Name: </strong>' . $name . '<br><strong>Date: </strong>' . $date . 
                         '<br><strong>Score: </strong>' . $score . '</p>';
                    echo '<form method="post" action="removescore.php">';
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="confirm" value="Yes">Yes ';
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="confirm" value="No" checked="checked">No ';
                    echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="score" value="' . $score . '">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="screenshot" value="' . $screenshot . '">';
                    echo '</form>';
                }
                echo '<p><a href="admin.php">&lt;&lt; Back to admin page</a></p>';                  
?>
```

I kept getting an error message saying that my id variable is undefined. After doing some research, I removed the text inside of the action quotes. Now it works, but I'm still wondering why the book teaches this way. Are they both valid options?

Comment: You're not getting the error (Notice) from the references to `$id` in this block.  Check the line number you're getting the Notice.

Comment: Where are those variables defined and how? And if the book was written in 2008, then it is old. PHP have come a _long_ way since then. Several API's have been both deprecated and removed since then.

Comment: I would be worried that this code isn't safe... I don't see any HTML escaping (such as `htmlspecialchars()`)...

Comment: This is my error message: Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\wamp64\www\guitarwars\guitarwars\removescore.php on line 45. This is  line 45: $query = "DELETE FROM guitarwars WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";

Comment: _Suggestion:_ When you're going to output a lot of html with just some PHP variables, it's better to close the PHP-block and inject the variables with: `<?= $id ?>` etc. Much more readable.

Comment: This is literally straight from the book. I'm worried I'm wasting time learning old/bad practices! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you're learning old practices. You should search for some tutorial that's up to date (preferably using PHP 7). Btw, that error message has nothing to do with the above code.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I edited the post to show more of the code so it makes more sense. I am getting the error message after I click on submit, so at this point $id should be defined through POST. I have spent hours trying to figure out why I'm getting the error message. However, when I change the form to read 'action=" " ' - I no longer get an error message. So I'm wondering if the way the book shows to self-reference is the problem. Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: That code leaves you _wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)_. You should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: I would stop following that book immediately! It's riddled with bad practices and insecure code!

Comment: `The book was written back in 2008 so I am constantly wondering if what I'm learning is up to date.` No, 2008 is not upto date, it's nearly a decade out of date. in web design (as a general rule) `up to date` is anything newer than 18-24 *months*.

Comment: forget the book: try using: http://www.phptherightway.com/

Answer (score 0):

A variable is echoed without quotes, so if you mix it with regular HTML code, you use the quotes for the HTML code, then end that with another quote of the same type - in your case a single quote.

But since the HTML code has to contain quotes (for the "value" attribute), you can mix single and double quotes as you did it.

The single quote before the variable ends the HTML echoing, the dot allows to connect a variable, after the variable a dot does the same, and then again single quotes for the HTML code.

Comment: I might be missing something, but doesn't the code in the question already do what you're explaining in your answer?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the question is "Now it works, but I'm still wondering why the book teaches this way"

Comment: That book should be tossed in the fire. It doesn't even escape the user inputs before using them in the sql query. Hello SQL Injections!

Comment: I am just now starting a chapter regarding security, so this is just a very basic beginner level walk-through assignment in the book... it looks like the next chapter touches on avoiding SQL Injections. Are you able to offer any resources where I can learn from that are more up to date?

Comment: @MelanieMarkarian Try google. There are literally thousands of "getting started" guides for PHP. Just make sure that they aren't 9 years old. I would be careful with a book that teaches the wrong way first, just to later change it.